# Optimization Problem with a ratio objective function

Tags: optimization

**Objective function:**
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
y_1 =& 10 & + 18x_1 & + 17x_2\\
y_2 =& 100& + 40x_1& + 41x_2
\end{array}
\right.
\qquad 
\text{and}
\qquad
k = \frac{y_1}{y_2}
$$

**Constraint to:**

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
15x_1 &+ 10x_2 &\leq 60 \\
30x_1 &+ 40x_2 &\leq 200
\end{array}
\right.
$$

How do I linearise the ratio?

Comment: Do you want to maximise or minimise the ratio?

Comment: I want to maximise it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is this :  [Linear fractional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming)